# Disabling dependency logging for Application insights on Azure app service (Web app)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

My application writes a lot of logs ib Dependencies which caused it to be super expensive (even more expensive than my server farms + database) and we have not used it for anything for months. 
How can I disable the dependencies but keep the rest (requests ,exceptions, custom events, etc.)?

In the documentation, adding application insights is not separated from adding dependencies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies

At the same time,

> in application insights resource >Usage and estimated costs

The only options avalable are

- Daily cap

-Data Sampling

But The custom events (and requests) have a great value for the business and I don't want them not to be logged because of a cap, or being sampled. 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need it, just remove the **DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule** from your ApplicationInsights.config file.

Look for this entry:

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
    .....
</Add>
```

And remove it or comment out:

```
<!--<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
    .....
</Add>-->
```

Another way is to set the sampling to 100% for Dependencies only. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#configuring-adaptive-sampling-for-aspnet-applications) for more information about that. But I think it is always better not to have something loaded or running what you don't need.

Comment: Thanks Marc, it worked on my local host, but not working on my Azure environment :(

Comment: hmm weird... have you double-checked the config file on azure with ftp or another tool?

Comment: Ah! I see! it is only the Ajax one! I've even added the filtering and it doesn't filter the ajax telemetry

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve that by creating a **telemetry processor** and disable the telemetry data within the `Process` method.

**Example:**

```
public void Process(ITelemetry item)
{
    var request = item as DependencyTelemetry;

    // Don't process dependency telemetry
    if (request != null)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.Next.Process(item);
}
```

See also: [Filtering and preprocessing telemetry in the Application Insights SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling)

Comment: This problem with this is that as far as I can tell the dependencies are still counted for adaptive sampling. So while it doesn't send them, it also massively samples your important events.